# How to replace values of one Google Sheet's column and import values of another automatically?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to replace several words in a URL that I have saved, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TQ0NJZSymHC2awsemLZ8Vcra4xlJVuIe4b1r6nmxklo/edit?usp=sharing
this is the sheet, it will help you get a clarity.

What I want is that there is a word - 'hottie' in the URL of google in the sheet and I want to replace the word hottie by all these domain names in the second column.

Any formula / way to do this? It'd mean a lot if any one can help! :)

Comment: Do you need to create several urls in which hottie will be replaced with column B values? or do you want to invoke the url changing hottie value?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `Replace & Find` to to replace all 'hottie' with the new text in another column:

```
=REPLACE(E1,FIND("hottie",E1),LEN("hottie"),F1)
```

[image]

Or with `arrayformula`:

```
=arrayformula(REPLACE(E:E,FIND("hottie",E:E),LEN("hottie"),F:F))
```

Comment: You are awesome man, This solved the query! Thank you so much

Comment: Accept the answer if solve you problem :)